# How to set up Istanbul code coverage with Angular 2 CLI?

Tags: angularjs, angular, istanbul

I am not sure I understand Istanbul set up.

All the tutorials only test one or two files.  How do you set it up so it tests your entire code base?  Am I understanding it wrong?

Comment: Which test framework are you using to write your tests?

Comment: well i think angular-cli @ webpack contains code coverage.  let me try and let you know.

Answer (score 3):

Without seeing exactly what you have going, I can show you my karma.conf which currently shows code coverage (although I haven't gotten it to work with Typescript just yet):

```
config.set({ 
    basePath: "./", 
    frameworks: ["jasmine"], 
    files: [            
        //load files here, including your spec and source files
    ],
    // Other settings...
    browsers: ["PhantomJS"],
    plugins: [
        "karma-jasmine",
        "karma-coverage", //<-- using karma-coverage for code coverage
        "karma-chrome-launcher",
        "karma-phantomjs-launcher"
    ],
    // Coverage reporter generates the coverage
    reporters: ["progress", "coverage"], //<-- reporter for code coverage
    // Source files that you wanna generate coverage for.
    // Do not include tests or libraries (these files will be instrumented by Istanbul)
    preprocessors: {
        "test/bin/js/app/**/!(*spec).js": ["coverage"] //<-- coverage pre-process
    }, 
    // Generate the code coverage report (lots of formats available)
    coverageReporter: {
        reporters:[
            { type: "html", dir: "./test/bin", subdir: "coverage/html" }
        ]
    },
    singleRun: true
})
```

In your `package.json`, include 
`"karma-coverage": "1.1.1"`
as a devDependency

Hopefully that points you in the right direction at least.

Comment: thanks this is really helpful!  let me try out angular-cli@webpack it has code coverage built in i think

Comment: I'm using angular-cli 1.0.0-beta.24 and generate coverage by running 'ng test --code-coverage'. It covers everything I write tests for. However, it also includes coverage for polyfills.ts and test.ts which I don't want but then misses coverage for any files that don't have tests - i.e. these should be 0% covered but they're just missing from coverage output.